# Suffix: -ierung vs. -ation

Tags: etymology, noun, suffix, latin

Es gibt viele Wörter, die wahrscheinlich aus dem Lateinischen stammen, die im Deutschen mit zwei verschiedenen Endungen möglich sind. Ich rede von den Endungen *-ierung* und *-ation*.

Beispiele:

- Registr-*ierung* / Registr-*ation*
- Isol-*ierung* / Isol-*ation*
- Realis-*ierung* / Realis-*ation*
- Form-*ierung* / Form-*ation*

Manchmal "fühlt" sich die eine Endung besser an als die andere und manchmal meine ich tatsächlich unterschiedliche Bedeutungen festmachen zu können. So ist die Isolierung eine Maßnahme zur Wärmedämmung und die Isolation *zusätzlich* noch eine soziale Abschottung. Sogar [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolierung) führt diese Begriffe synonym.

Woher kommt diese doppelte Endung? Wann ist welche zu verwenden? Oder bedeuten sie tatsächlich in *jedem Fall* dasselbe?

Comment: Registration? In einem deutschen Satz ist mir dieses Wort noch nie untergekommen. Google liefert bei "registration" hauptsächlich englischsprachige Treffer.

Comment: Das kann gut sein! Ich benutze beide Sprachen ungefähr gleich viel und da ist mir wohl ein neuer Anglizismus rübergerutscht. Aber nach der Erklärung des Duden müsste dieses Wort doch (rein theoretisch) auch verwendbar sein, oder?

Comment: Wir haben in der deutschen Sprache ausreichend Wörter. Ich halte es nicht für notwendig aus anderen Sprache Begriffe zu importieren, wenn die deutsche Sprache dafür bereits gut etablierte Vokabel mit genau derselben Bedeutung bereithält.

Comment: sehr schöne Frage !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_ation__ierung) scheint eine Antwort dafür zu haben.

Nomen, die auf *-ierung* oder *-ation* enden sind von Verben, die auf *-ieren* enden, abgeleitet. Diese Verben stammen wohl alle aus dem Lateinischen.

*-ierung* und *-ation* ändern nichts an der Bedeutung eines Wortes. Beide Endungen können synonym verwendet werden. Allerdings sind manchmal unterschiedliche Bedeutungsnuancen festzustellen. So bezeichnen *-ation* Wörter stärker das Ergebnis einer Handlung und *-ierung* Wörter mehr das Geschehen selbst.

Im Isolierungs / Isolations Beispiel ist eine solche leichte Nuancierung gegeben. Isolierung wird im technischen Kontext verwendet, wobei Isolation im wissenschaftlichen Kontext Verwendung findet.

Eine weitere Möglichkeit der Erklärung nach cfaerber:
Der Unterschied bei der Bildung der Formen kommt daher, dass in einem Fall zuerst das Verb aus dem Lateinischen eingedeutscht und dann das deutsche Verb substantiviert wird, während im anderen Fall zuerst eine Substantivierung im Lateinischen erfolgt und dann das lateinische Substantiv eingedeutscht wird.

- registrare (Verb, lat.) => registrieren (Verb, dt.) => Registrierung (Substantiv, dt.)
- registrare (Verb, lat.) => registratio (Substantiv, lat.) => Registration (Substantiv, dt.)

Comment: "-ierung und -ation ändern nichts an der Bedeutung eines Wortes." -- I strongly disagree. Of the four examples the OP gives, at least two have very different meaning. [Em1's answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/4959/6010) aptly illustrates this.

Answer (score 3):

Technisch gesehen kann es durchaus richtig sein, dass man die Endung austauschen kann und die Bedeutung des Wortes sich nicht ändert, dennoch gibt es Wörter, die ich niemals mit der einen oder anderen Endung verwenden würde. Des Weiteren würde ich auch – ohne weiteren Kontext – bei manchen Wörtern komplett andere Vorstellungen haben, was sich dahinter verbirgt.

Bei Isolation denke ich spontan an die [soziale Isolation](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soziale_Isolation). Hört man heutzutage gerne schon mal in den Nachrichten, wenn es um einen Amokläufer oder so geht, aber auch allgemein beim Thema Mobbing. Und, auch wenn es sich dabei nicht mehr direkt um *soziale* Isolation handelt, wenn sich Nationen abkapseln, z. B. [Nordkorea](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordkorea#Isolation).

> Nordkoreas Isolation wird zur Gefahr <sup>[Zeit.de](http://www.zeit.de/politik/ausland/2010-11/china-nordkorea-aggression-wikileaks)</sup>

Dank Wikipedia kenne ich nun auch die *biologische Definition* von [Isolation](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28Biologie%29).

Beim Stichwort Isolierung hingegen denke ich eher an [Bauwerksabdichtung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauwerksabdichtung), sei es zur Schall- oder Wärmeisolierung. Oder die Isolierung bei Kabeln, so dass Störeinflüsse geringer bis gar nicht auf das Medium einwirken können. Jedoch findet man unter dem Stichwort Isolation auch insbesondere Referenzen zur Kabelabschirmung, und sogar Texte, in denen die Wörter vermischt werden (wenngleich auch mit einer Tendenz zu dem einen oder anderen). Ein Beispiel dafür ist der Wikipediaartikel zu [Isolator](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolator).

Und letztlich listet Wikipedia unter [Isolierung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolierung) weitere Beispiele, bei denen entweder Isolierung oder Isolation bevorzugt wird, oder gar vermischt werden. So scheint bei der [Schwingungsisolierung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwingungsisolierung) die Verwendung von Isolation eher Seltenheit zu sein. Aber tatsächlich wird keine strikte Differenzierung ([Differentiation](http://www.mathematik.de/ger/fragenantworten/erstehilfe/differentiation/differentiationimrn/differentiationimrn.html)?) zwischen Isolierung und Isolation gezogen.

Wie dem auch sei, ich kenne mich mit den meisten dieser Themen bestenfalls bedingt aus und kann daher überhaupt kein Urteil darüber fällen. Was ich aber mit Sicherheit sagen kann, ist, dass ich noch nie *soziale Isolierung* gehört habe, und bei Schall- oder Wärmeisolierung ist mir das Wort Isolation in der Tat fremd. Das mag eventuell regional bedingt sein oder auch allgemein gültig.

An dieser Stelle sei aber auch gesagt, dass natürlich auch Quellen existieren, die meinem persönlichen Empfinden widersprechen, so zum Beispiel finden sich auch Artikel über die *Isolierung von Nordkorea* unter den Suchergebnissen bei Google.

Bzgl. der anderen Wörter: Zu Formation und Formierung könnte ich ähnliche Worte verlieren, wie gerade über Isolierung und Isolation. Registration, wie schon in einem Kommentar von Hubert Schölnast gesagt wurde, sowie Realisation klingen für mich fremd und äußerst ungewohnt. Zumindest im Deutschen. Gleiches gilt für Implementation, wo ich immer zu Implementierung greifen würde. Was alles nicht heißt, dass ihre Verwendung nicht vorhanden wäre, oder gar falsch. Es ist nur unüblich und daher selten zu sehen.

Um nun ein Schlusswort zu finden:
Es gibt Tendenzen, mal die eine oder mal die andere Endung zu bevorzugen. Teilweise ist es für ein Wort allgemeingültig, manchmal abhängig vom eigentlichen Kontext. Man wird aber mit der *anderen* Endung nicht falsch verstanden (sofern Kontext gegeben) und man wird auch niemanden verwirren, auf die falsche Fährte locken oder sonst wie aus dem Konzept bringen, nur weil man die *ungewohnte* Endung verwendet. Möglicherweise fällt es dem Gegenüber nicht mal unbedingt auf.

Comment: +1, sehr gute Antwort. Und wenn ich könnte, würde ich noch ein +1 für das völlige Fehlen von wiktionary, dict.leo.org, dict.cc und duden.de vergeben.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Warum ist das Fehlen von Referenzen Lob wert?

Comment: @Raphael Ich glaub ihm ging es vor allen Dingen darum, dass die genannten Referenzen von vielen als das Non-Plus-Ultra angesehen werden, dabei aber in aller Regel aber irreführend oder gar falsch sind.

Comment: @Em1 Bei den von der Community gepflegten Angeboten kann man definitiv reinfallen, aber Duden sollte schon eine Referenz im wahrsten Sinne des Wortes sein, oder? (Außerdem ist seine eigene Aussage durch Angabe mehrere Quellen, die das Gleiche sagen, zu belegen ja nicht das Gleiche wie diese Quellen nur blind abzuschreiben.)